# AS3 delete dictionary[key] in Haxe

Tags: actionscript-3, haxe, code-translation

I have come across this when using [as3hx](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/as3hx) to port my AS3 code to Haxe:

```
delete classMemberDictionary[key]
```

as3hx can't translate this to Haxe, you have to do it manually. I've read the 
as3hx README and it says

> 1. if it is a local variable, replace `delete varname` with `varname = null`
> 2. if it is a class member variable, remove the `delete` entirely

Since it is a dictionary item it doesn't seem right to just remove the line, as the README says. Should I set it to `null`?

Comment: What are your key types? You may want to translate `flash.utils.Distionary` to a `haxe.ds.ObjectMap`, if your keys are objects / instances. If the keys are `String`, use `haxe.ds.StringMap`. And either way, as @gama11 says, use `remove()` for deleting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using [`Map`](https://haxe.org/manual/std-Map.html) or [`openfl.utils.Dictionary`](https://api.openfl.org/openfl/utils/Dictionary.html?)? In either case you can use `remove()`:

- [`Map.remove()`](https://api.haxe.org/Map.html?#remove)
- [`Dictionary.remove()`](https://api.openfl.org/openfl/utils/Dictionary.html?#remove)

Setting the value to `null` isn't quite the same. Although `get()` would return `null` in either case, `exists()` still returns `true` for entries that weren't explicitly removed.